# How to select the association based on the Parent Class in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I am creating a web application where I need to fetch the order based on the orderId but they should be linked to the parent class.

```
public class StudentOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class EmployeeOrder
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have the OrderId and I need to fetch the details of the order.

```
NhSession.QueryOver<StudentOrder>()
    .Where(x => x.Orders.Any(y => y.Id == id)).SingleOrDefault();
```

How can I get by queryOver() and get the order details by Id. I dont want to query over directly over orders as they are linked with both different entity

Answer (score 0):

QueryOver can navigate association paths using JoinQueryOver() as documented [here](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/12/17/queryover-in-nh-3-0.aspx). Example:

```
var studentOrder = NhSession.QueryOver<StudentOrder>()
                            .JoinQueryOver(so => so.Orders)
                            .Where(o => o.Id == orderId);
```